# error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have a situation like below code, but I am getting error C2512:  no appropriate default constructor available error

```
class A
{
};

class AProxy :public A
{
    A* ptr;
public:
    AProxy(A* var):ptr(var){}
};

class B : public A
{
};

class BProxy : public virtual B, public virtual AProxy
{
    B* ptr;
public :
    BProxy(B* var):AProxy(var),ptr(var){}
};

class C : public B
{
};

class CProxy  : public virtual BProxy, public virtual C
{
    C* ptr;
public :
    CProxy(C* var):BProxy(var),ptr(var){}
};
```

I am not getting why this is giving such error.
Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Please check this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907722/why-is-default-constructor-called-in-virtual-inheritance).

Your problem is in `virtual` inheritance. You need to call `AProxy` constructor in your initialization list of `CProxy` constructor:

```
public :
CProxy(C* var):BProxy(var), AProxy(var),ptr(var){}
```

Comment: And why is that? `CProxy` is calling `BProxy` which is already calling `AProxy`

Comment: Because, when using virtual inheritance, virtual base constructor is called from most derived class.